# Existence of theories with exactly two countable models

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

I read a result of [Vaught](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_theory)(a little down the page) that says that there cannot be any first order theory which has exactly two countable models upto isomorphism. Is this not a counter example:

The theory of dense linear orders(DLO) has 4 countable models upto isomorphism. They are  the intervals $[0,1]$, $(0,1)$, $[0,1)$, and $(0,1]$ (restricted to the rationals). If to DLO we add the statement that there is a lower bound, do we not end up with exactly two of these 4 theories?

Am I misunderstanding Vaught's result or making a mistake with the DLO part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vaught's result says that a **complete** theory cannot have precisely two countable models (up to isomorphism). The theory you suggest does have precisely two models, but it is not complete.

Comment: Oh yes! I completely missed that. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome.